# Is there a way to send JSON/String back to change the original data?

Tags: php, json, jira-rest-api

I set up Jira and now want to start by changing some of the details about my own profile. Right now I have the code to get the JSON with my profile information, can I somehow send that back and change the information with it?

```
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test123';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=test');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$wantedString = json_decode($query);
print_r($wantedString->name);
$wantedString->name = 'test1';
print_r($wantedString);
```

For anyone wondering I use Jira Rest API

*https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/customFieldOption-getCustomFieldOption*

Comment: That depends on the REST API you are using. Please refer to the documentation of the specific API in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation the Api supports changes to users.

https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/user-updateUser

or if you want to change the data of the current login user:

https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/myself-updateUser